# How to make images look good on both nexus and nexus 10?

Tags: android, xml, screen-resolution

I'm trying to make my app workable and visually better across all different screen sizes, but I have run into some issues. I have a simple image layout : [image]

The images are sized 200 x 200 for small and 400 x 400 for the large. In the drawable folders I have made some smaller ones for smaller screens 100x100 , 200x200 and then 50x50 , 100x100. However looking at the list of devices in eclipse, the galaxy nexus 10 and the galaxy nexus both take their images from the xdpi folder. If I make the images work for the nexus its makes the nexus 10 really small and if I make them for the nexus 10 it messes up the layout for other devices.  Why doesn't the nexus 10 just use the xxhdpi folder ?

How can I get around this issue ? I want to avoid separate layouts if possible as I've not attempted that yet as i'm still new to android programming.

How can solve this issue ?

Go easy on me as im still quite new. Thanks

### edit

Listed as galaxy nexus in eclipse (720 x 1280)
and Nexus 10 (2560 x 1600)

as you can see major difference in sizes but use the same xdpi folder

Comment: which two devices are you trying to make this work on?

Comment: I would create two folders, one for 720x1280 and one for 2560x1600

Comment: Im trying to make it work on all devices really. But the ones I have issues with are the 4.7inch galaxy nexus and the nexus 10 as they use the same xdpi folder. If I make the images nice and big for the nexus 10 it also messes up my Samsung s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare drawables for different screen widths

`drawable-sw720dp/`

Comment: Got it looking ok using this drawable folder however its still a little confusing to me as it didn't accept the larger images I designed for the bigger screen however the normal size images that were tiny before in the xdpi folder now look ok when stored in the folder above!?

Comment: @Xeo yes this is also in the android documentation for supporting multiple screens. For you want to do its diffidently worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

It suggests that you create different layouts to support the different sizes.
If this become to much work you can restrict which sizes you support in the manifest.

So as i said in the comment above, I would create two folders, one for 720x1280 and one for 2560x1600.

I would then add a layout to each of the ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high) if you want to try and support as many as possible.

Sorry I don't know any shortcuts. If i find anything else I'll add to this answer.

Comment: Funnily enough I was currently reading that link for more information when you posted it. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, yeah its a shame there isn't an easier way to make one screen to fit all...